# How do I concatenate lines from a text file into one big string?

Tags: text-files, string-concatenation

I have an input file that looks like(without such big spaces between lines):

3 4

ATCGA

GACTTACA

AACTGTA

ATC

...and I need to concatenate all lines except for the first "3 4" line.  Is there a simple solution? I've tried manipulating getline() somehow, but that has not worked for me.

Edit: The amount of lines will not be known initially, so it will have to be done recursively.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Answer (score 0):

If your concate 2 lines in 1 line then you can use easily concate "+",

e.g:

```
String a = "WAQAR MUGHAL";
String b = "check";

System.out.println(a + b);

System.out.println("WAQAR MUGHAL" + "CHECK");
```

Output:

```
WAQAR MUGHAL check
WAQAR MUGHAL CHECK
```

Comment: I wish it were just that easy, but it is going to have to be some sort of loop to add each line, regardless of how many.

Comment: Use *StringBuffer* or *StringBuilder* based on requirement,  above approach in not efficient in terms of implementation its solve problem but not recommended way..